# UWP MediaCapture CreateHEVC Video Encoding Bitrate Too Slow

Tags: uwp, video-capture

I am using CreateHEVC with the VideoQuality parameter set to HD1080p after which I set the video.bitrate = 6000000.  The source is a 1080p HDMI camera fed through a USB converter.  This issue I have is that the resultant recording is at 68kbs not the requested 6Mbs and the video is basically a still frame.   If I set the VideoQuality parameter to Auto, it creates the video properly, but at a bitrate of 12Mbs, much too high for what we require with HEVC.  As this method seems to work with other cameras, it must be sensitive to the input of this one.  AmCap reads it as 1080p, so not sure what is going on.  Perhaps someone has run into this scenario before and have suggestions on how to handle this situation.

Comment: According to your description, it seems you only have the problem with one camera and other cameras can work. Do I understand it correctly? Anyway, I tried set [Bitrate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.mediaproperties.videoencodingproperties#Bitrate) in my side and it works well. Maybe the problem here is with the camera you are using.

Comment: I finally found what the problem was.  The camera defaulted to a 60 fps rate causing the strange encoding rates.  I changed to input format selection to require 30 fps and the HEVC recordings returned the proper expected rates.